# How to move the Handle of the Angular Material Slider dynamically with the value property

Tags: angular, angular-material

I use the mat-slider from angular material for a formular somewhat like this:

```
<mat-slider thumbLabel value="this.objectArray[i].numberProperty"></mat-slider>
```

The problem is that the handle of the slider just stays at the beginning. The weird part is that when i hard-code it in like this:

```
<mat-slider thumbLabel value="5"></mat-slider>
```

Then it works for some reason.

If i use [(ngModel)] on an input like the following it works, but [(ngModel)] isnt compatible with the mat-slider as far as i know

```
<input type="number" [(ngModel)]="presentationSlideTimes[i].slidetime">
```

Hope you guys can help me <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try binding it as an input instead, since it's an angular value. You have two options there:

```
<mat-slider thumbLabel [value]="this.objectArray[i].numberProperty"></mat-slider>
```

Or:

```
<mat-slider thumbLabel value="{{this.objectArray[i].numberProperty}}"></mat-slider>
```

They should both work. Also, as far as I am concerned, mat-slider does implement ControlValueAccessor so it should also support [(ngModel)].

Answer (score 2):

Who told you that it's not compatible?
Material team use it in [the example](https://material.angular.io/components/slider/examples).
Feel free to use it ;)
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add square bracket to the following value attribute

```
<mat-slider thumbLabel [value]="this.objectArray[i].numberProperty"></mat-slider>
```